# Visual Studio debugging checks out files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I'm opening a solution we have (for a web site) that has several projects in it in Visual Studio 2015.  Everything seems fine.  The site is up and running, I can view pages, and the solution is loaded into Visual Studio.  I then want to debug, so I attach to my w3wp process...and Visual Studio goes nuts and checks out about 11,000 files in my solution.

I don't expect someone to know exactly what is going on since I haven't given the relevant details (because I don't know what those details would be.)  My question is more general...what would cause Visual Studio to start checking out (tons of) files when starting to debug?

Answer (score 0):

You may have the following in your .sln file:

```
GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
MyGlobalProperty = AnyValue
EndGlobalSection
```

This could have been added by the Unity NuGet package or the Enterprise Library.
If you remove this and recheck in the solution this should prevent the problem.

Comment: Sounded promising, but no luck.  No such GlobalSection in the sln file.